# Отсутствует поле "item" - ошибка в Гугл вебмастере

Tags: wordpress, микроразметка

Всем привет, может поможет кто разобраться. Ругается на цепочку крошек, может я упустил что-то из виду.

Отсутствует поле "item" - ошибка в Гугл вебмастере

Ругается вот на этот кусок кода:

Главная

Код в шаблоне такой:

// Open the unordered list.
$breadcrumb .= '';

// Add the number of items and item list order schema.
$breadcrumb .= sprintf( '', absint( $item_count ) );
$breadcrumb .= '';

// Loop through the items and add them to the list.
foreach ( $this->items as $item ) {

```
// Iterate the item position.
++$item_position;

// Check if the item is linked.
preg_match( '/(<a.*?>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/i', $item, $matches );

// Wrap the item text with appropriate itemprop.
$item = !empty( $matches ) ? sprintf( '%s<span itemprop="name">%s</span>%s', $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3] ) : sprintf( '<span itemprop="name">%s</span>', $item );

// Add list item classes.
$item_class = 'trail-item';

if ( 1 === $item_position && 1 < $item_count )
    $item_class .= ' trail-begin';

elseif ( $item_count === $item_position )
    $item_class .= ' trail-end';

// Create list item attributes.
$attributes = 'itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="' . $item_class . '"';

// Build the meta position HTML.
$meta = sprintf( '<meta itemprop="position" content="%s" />', absint( $item_position ) );

// Build the list item.
$breadcrumb .= sprintf( '<li %s>%s%s</li>', $attributes, $item, $meta );
}
```

// Close the unordered list.
$breadcrumb .= '';

Помогите разобраться где что поправить?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/14850974?hl=ru

Comment: Сделал, но все равно пишет ошибку
Скрин - http://joxi.ru/n2YnvNVfb6XDkA